# Move randomly Item inside Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm curently working on a new site, An I need to move randomly the neews feed
Actualy I build an Array with thes news list. The array is shuffled and put at the place of the news feed.

This trick work well, but i want to add some animation, effect to show the item move.

my HTML is like below :

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <a href="...">news content</a>
   <a href="...">news content</a>
   <a href="...">news content</a>
</div>
```

so it's the `<a>` element that i need to animate inside the `<div>`

any idea of how can I do that ?

Comment: use marquee then prefect for news etc http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm check this link for animation

Comment: Please check http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: Simply saying `animate` is too broad. be specific. BTW, did you try anything..? read some tutorials or articles on animation..?

Comment: @M.chaudhry link works for me.

Comment: @M.chaudhry: Can you please check now. It works fine for me.

Comment: @SyncCircles it did work now :)

Comment: Did somebody seriously just suggest using a `<marquee>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most common way of making simple animations is using jQuery. I hope you're familiar with it, otherwise take a look [over here](http://learn.jquery.com/).

I've made [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelvandeweerd/2JwH9/2/) with my solution to your problem with lots of comments.

What that code basically does is calculating the amount of elements that should be moved and then giving every element a top margin in a random order. The tricky part is keeping track of the elements that have been given a top margin, so I'm pushing their id's into an array.

You should also be aware that I've given every link element an id like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a id="1">news content 1</a>
    <a id="2">news content 2</a>
    <a id="3">news content 3</a>
    <a id="4">news content 4</a>
    etc...
</div>
```

All link elements **must** have an id like that. Also, all links should have the `display: block;` attribute in their CSS. I hope you like my solution, good luck!

Comment: hell yeah, that great, I was trting somthing else with some `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` but not succesfully. Im my case the `<a>` element can have diferent heigh and width in one or two column (responsive design)